# What lifetime does continuationToken have in Azure CosmosDB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

We are using continuationTokens for paging query results in Azure Cosmos DB.

According to documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/pagination#continuation-tokens

> In the .NET SDK and Java SDK, you can optionally use continuation tokens as a bookmark for your query's progress. Azure Cosmos DB for NoSQL query executions are stateless at the server side and can be resumed at any time using the continuation token.

1. I wonder how long each continuation token is persisted in my Azure CosmosDB account?
2. Can I cleanup/delete continuation tokens?
3. Is the continuation tokens stored on container or account level?
4. Are there any limits in how many stored continuation tokens I can use?

Comment: There is no server side state stored for continuation tokens. ("stateless at the server side") The token itself has enough information about where to resume from

Comment: Can you clarify which Operation you are obtaining the token from? A Query?

Comment: Yes for a query and pagination if many pages.

Comment: Very unclear why this was closed as "opinion based" IMO - I get the impression that the Azure Collective may be incentivising this sort of behaviour as not the first time I have seen this sort of weird closure in the CosmosDB tag